# Laravel and intervention imagecache generate too many queries (1 query per image)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with Intervention Imagecache

I'm writing a store, and the products page have many images. I'm using [URL-based manipulation](http://image.intervention.io/use/url) (e.g. accessing http://store.app/image/255x135/some-image.jpg generates a 255x135 version of some-image.jpg) for resizing the images.
When the image is loaded, however, Laravel generates a query that checks the user (select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1)

The problem is that this query is generated every time any route in Laravel is accessed, including the Intervention Imagecache route, and when the page loads 20-30 images using Intervention, the above user-check SQL query is executed for every image (in this 20-30 times).

While I was trying to figure out the problem I noticed that this query is generated for every single route in Laravel, even a simple test route, in other words the problem is not with Intervention Imagecache itself.

I'm currently trying to disable the user-check query on the Intervention route but I'm yet to succeed.

My 2 questions are:

1. Can the user-check query be disabled for a specific route?
2. Is there a way around this query-per-image problem (except resizing images and saving them to the filesystem - in other words abandoning the URL-based manipulation)?

**EDIT**

At first I was debugging with DB::listen() which showed multiple queries being executed (1 query for every Intervention route being accessed)

I just installed and checked what Clockwork would show and it indeed shows only 1 query (not multiple queries, so Clockwork says everything is OK).

I was not sure which of these conflicting results were true, so I logged the queries directly from MySQL itself - unfortunately it showed that many (same amount as DB::listen logged) queries were executed (**Clockwork showed only 1, but several were actually executed**).

The problem remains, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use encode() to display the images

Comment: Can you give me an example? If I access the imagecache route in any way a query is executed.

Comment: Do you use Auth middleware with that route?

Comment: No, but that's not the problem. Every route accessed checks if the user is logged. Maybe because of the presence of the login cookies. I still haven't found a way around this.

Comment: I'm using Intervention plugin but I don't experience user-check in every route. only routes I apply Auth middleware on them.